# Set which includes odd numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

"Let $k$ be and odd number, or more generally suppose that $k \equiv \pm 4^a \mod 4^b$ with $a<b$."
Does that set contain all odd numbers?
I could verify for all odd numbers that are one less of a power of $4$, but how can you get the others?

Comment: $k \equiv \pm 4^a \bmod 4^b$ implies $k$ even if $a>1$.

Comment: If $a=0$ and $b=1$ , we get $k\equiv \pm 1 \mod 4$ , which is exactly the condition for an odd number. If $a>0$ , $k$ is always even.